# From a vector of `int` to a sequence of bits

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

`y` is an unsigned integer which represents a list of bits. `v` is a vector of integers containing only 0 and 1. I would like to set the values of `v` into `y` in an efficient manner. I would do

```
for (int i ; i<v.size() ; ++i)
{
  y ^= (-v[i] ^ y) & (1 << i);
}
```

Is this efficient or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Does `v[0]` represent the least significant bit or the most significant bit? Your code needs to be different based on the answer to that.

Comment: May be something using a `std::bitset`. Refrain using `std::vector<bool>`. Also define __efficient please.

Comment: You're aware of great phrase about 'premature optimization' by Donald Knuth I hope

Comment: @agg3l Now, I am. I am certain that I will need to optimize memory usage through the usage of bitwise operations. This particular for loop will run many times but it is right that I am not quite sure what is its relative importance in total CPU time. I asked the question mainly to improve my understanding of bitwise manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I asked the question mainly to improve my understanding of bitwise manipulations" - If that's the case then:

You are using two *^* [xor] ops, one *&* [union] op and one *<<* [left shift] op, you can achieve the same by using one *<<* [left shift] op and one *|* [intersect] op.

Something like this:

```
for (int i; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    y <<= 1;
    y |= v[i];
}
```

Comment: That reverses the order but apparently OP is OK with that